# Effective design for related classes that use unrelated classes

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have following situation and would like to know the best way to design my solution

```
public abstract class A {
  public abstract A getHelper();
  public abstract void launchHandle();  
  public static A initHelper(String condition) throws Exception {
      if ( condition == 'xyz') {
         return C.getHelper();
      } else {
          return B.getHelper();
      }
  }
}

public class B extends A {
  protected static A b;

  @Override
  public A getHelper() {
    b = new B();
    return b;
  }

 @Override
  public void launchHandle() {
   System.out.println("Launching Handle");
  }

  public String getName() {
   return "I am from Class B";
  }
}

public class C extends A {
  protected static A c;

  @Override
  public A getHelper() {
    c = new C();
    return c;
  }

 @Override
  public void launchHandle() {
   System.out.println("Launching Handle from C");
  }

  public String getValue() {
   return "I am from Class C";
  }
}

**Executor class**

public class Executor {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      A aa = a.initHelper(condition);
   }
}
```

Now in the above approach, i am unable to access methods like aa.getName() from Class B OR aa.getValue() from Class C, which makes sense. However how to get these methods in executor class? Executor does not know anything about Class B & C and should not know. Executor is only aware of Class A, but want to access methods SubClass methods from B & C which are extended from Class A.

Please help design this and what could be best way to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: But passing parameters won't solve the problem. I think you are suggesting to pass two Object param1 and Object param2 and then return b or c, But remember Executor does not know about b or c neither can type cast to these objects. single quote is typo..i just wrote this sample program quickly based on my need.

Comment: For what purpose do you need to access aa.getName() and aa.getValue() ?? Can you please add a code snippets for that (@ least the idea)? And what do you exactly mean by  "Executor does not know anything about Class B & C and should not know" ??

Comment: @iamMobile How does the call `C.getHelper()` even work? `getHelper` is not a `static` method..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Executor is only aware of Class A, but want to access methods SubClass methods from B & C which are extended from Class A.

If you take a closer look at your code, you will notice that the only contract constant across all your classes is the `launchHandle` method (baring `getHelper` and `initHelper` which are simply used for instantiating the right subclass). There is no real relation between `B` and `C` other than the fact that their instantiation is controlled by `A`.

This is how I would consider approaching the problem :

**Executor Factory**

Make `Executor` an `abstract` class rather than making it the entry point of your program :

```
public abstract class Executor {
    public abstract void performTask();
    public static void execute(String condition) {
       Executor executor = null;
       if ( condition.equals("xyz")) {
          executor = new AExector();
       } else {
          executor = new BExecutor();
       }
       executor.performTask();
    }

}
```

**Executor implementations**

Create a different implementation for operating on `B` called `BExecutor` :

```
public class BExecutor extends Executor {

    public void performTask() {
      System.out.println("launching handle from B");
      //create or get data to perform the task on
      B b = new B();
      String name = b.getName();
      System.out.println("I am from "+name);

    }
}
```

Create a different implementation for operating on `C` called `CExecutor` :

```
public class CExecutor extends Executor {


    public void performTask() {
      System.out.println("launching handle from C");
       //create or get data to perform the task on
      C c = new C();
      String value = c.getValue();
      System.out.println("I am from "+value);

    }
}
```

Your main method can then look like this :

```
public static void main(String []args) { 
   Executor executor = Executor.execute(condition);
}
```

And for some reason, if you do find some common contract between `B` and `C`, you an always create an `interface` which both `B` and `C` can implement and use a reference of this `interface` instead of using a `B` or `C` reference.

Answer (score 1):

Add getName and getValue to A as abstract methods.

Comment: I thought about it but class B & class C (and will have many more extended from A), so A will start becoming unmanageable if i keep adding abstract methods in A based on class B & C needs.

Comment: I still don't see why you can't just do what you did with launchHandle. Just create a new abstract method, and have all the subclasses implement it differently.

Comment: Thanks Alex, i can definitely do that and it works too. But the problem i see is there are at least 6 more classes which will extend A and each of these classes have at least 20 Unique methods. Now that means i will have 120 abstract methods in Class A. It is fine to do but i was looking for a better approach where i keep only common methods in Class A and rest remain it's own classes.

Comment: This is one of the issues with inheritance rather than composition. Consider using interfaces and well defined contracts as to what objects will do. Concepts such as dependency injection should help, as your potential 120 method abstract class sounds like it's doing too much.